# Get 2nd Value in Dataset in Reporting Services

Tags: ssrs-2008

This seems to be a very simple question, but I am trying to get the 2nd value in a dataset to display as a matrix's header value.

In this report, lets say that I have 2 datasets.  In Dataset1, I have a query that pulls down 3 values for a parameter dropdown selection.  In Dataset2, I return a result set and have bound it to my matrix.

Within the matrix, I have my repeating columns, and then 3 additional grouped columns to the right that have aggrigate values that I want to display.  On the header of those 3 columns, I want to display the 3 values displayed in my Parameters dataset.  Within the context of the matrix (and its dataset), I can get the first and last values of a different dataset (Dataset1 in this case) by using:

```
=First(Fields!DateDisplay.Value, "Dataset1")
=Last(Fields!DateDisplay.Value, "Dataset1")
```

I need to get something like:

```
=Second(Fields!DateDisplay.Value, "Dataset1")
```

How do I pull this off without violating the scoping rules on aggregate columns?

Answer (score 9):

For SSRS 2008 R2, you can do this if each row of your dataset has an identifier column by using the [LookUp() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx).

```
=LookUp(1,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!DateDisplay.Value,”Dataset1”)
=LookUp(2,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!DateDisplay.Value,”Dataset1”)
=LookUp(3,Fields!Row.Value,Fields!DateDisplay.Value,”Dataset1”)
```

If you do not have an identifier column you can use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to build one in.

**Query:**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateDisplay) AS Row, DateDisplay
FROM Dates
```

**Results:**

```
Row DateDisplay
--- ---------
1   June 1st    
2   March 12th      
3   November 15th
```

Here is a link to a similar thread in MSDN Forums: [Nth row element in a dataset SSRS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/20493945-578a-4d83-ae3b-e603a3473ac6)

Comment: This is incorrect - if you try this in SSRS 2008r2 you get an error stating that the Lookup Function has an incorrect amount of parameters. It takes 4 not 3. I would vote this down but i can't!

Comment: @leinad13 I have edited the posting. This should be more clear now. My mistake, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @dotNetE  Looks like you have the parameters in the wrong order, should be =LookUp(2, Fields!Row.Value,Fields!DateDisplay.Value,”Dataset1”)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SSRS-2012 or 2014 then one has to use below expression.

```
=LookUp(AnyRowNumber, Fields!RowNumber.Value,Fields!DisplayField.Value,”DatasetName”)
```

*I have tried above it was not working in my case.*